# SQL performance on one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 510,085 rows, which is now pushing me to seek higher performance. One of the fields in this table is called 'photoStatus'.

In 'photoStatus', 510,045 rows contain the word 'Active' and the remaining 40 contain the word 'Suspended'.

Which of these two queries would be faster to search for 'Active' photos or doesn't it matter?

```
WHERE photoStatus = 'Active'

Or

WHERE photoStatus <> 'Suspended'
```

Obviously this is part of a massive query, it's not just one WHERE condition.

**Database is MySQL (MyISAM)**

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Not sure what database system you're using - but in SQL Server, both queries will be really slow, since the only way SQL Server can determine this is by scanning the table (or its clustered index) since the "Active" status entries make up the bulk of the data. No index will really help much here.... also depends on whether you're selecting everything (`SELECT *`) or whether you might have a query that can be handled by a covering index, i.e an index that can return all the values you need - then maybe SQL Server could do an index scan on a smaller index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not convert the column to a boolean, or a numeric value, which would be much faster than a string compare, then you could just do:

```
  ....
  WHERE isActive;
```

Comment: Yes, i think that this would be the best to get more speed in your query. can you try this?

Comment: This was a smidgen faster yes. I'm using MySQL so I used INT(1) instead of a boolean type and ran "WHERE photoStatus;". Not a lot but a little better, especially as there are two WHERE conditions similar to this in my query.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index on that column `WHERE photoStatus = 'Active'` will be faster since the server can just scan the range in the index matching `Active`.

Comment: Maybe - but sine the data is very skewed (> 99% "Active" and just a fraction "Suspended"), I assume SQL Server's query optimizer will just do a scan - no matter what index you have...

Answer (score 0):

Second will be "a little" faster because it will not require to compare whole string just first character comparison is enough to include result according to database comparison algo

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use an index on that field. And EXPLAIN the query to see how efficient your query is.

Other than that your query would filter out just 40, so the rest of the query has to be efficient.

Comment: in this scenario an index wouldn't help

Answer (score 0):

Its going to have to index the table and rows either way.

Personally I would always match. Use equals.

```
WHERE photoStatus = 'Active'
```

I would always use int or boolean, better than matching a string..

Answer (score 0):

A normal index won't help in this scenario since the percentage of actually returned rows is to large.

So the database will have to look at each row. There might be some differenece, depending on how fast an equal vs !equal comparison is, but that should be neglectable.

So I expect the result to be pretty much of same speed.

Answer (score 0):

You have posted to few details to find a shortcut for your query.

As it appears you need a full scan.  In this case you can try to read the table in parallel.
Don't know what DBMS you use, but in Oracle you can use a hint `select /*+parallel(yourtable  8)*/ from yourtable`

What you try to do with this data? What types of queryes are slow? can you give an example?There can be many tricks and you can do many mistakes. And not all queryes should work fast. If they are for UI, must respond in a time < 1s. But if it is for admin task, may take 1 minute :)

Answer (score 0):

WHERE photoStatus = 'Active' is better if you have index on that column based on small testing similar to your example.

I added query execution in sql server. Short one belongs to equal comparison. It is reporting better performance. If you dont have index, query cost is similar.

[image: where statusname = 'Active']

[image: where statusname <> 'Suspend']

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, .5M rows is not a large table - by ANY means.

A column like "Active" / "Inactive", is likely to be pretty useless to be an index by itself, because it doesn't have enough selectivity to make an index scan beneficial (in fact, if it's 50% of the rows in the table, a table-scan would probably be better).

I suspect that in fact, "Active" has nothing to do with your problem - after all, you're not trying to return .5M rows to the client are you?

A query which returns .5M rows is not going to be fast, because just returning the rows takes a (relatively) long time.

Anyway my answer: It makes no difference, you need to check the other parts of your query. Post a question with the full query, table structure and explain output.